# How do I allocate a struct with a given char array using strdup?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, initialization

So I have a typedef struct called cmd_t with a character array member called argv.
And I have a function that takes a character array argument and I want it to initialize the struct with an array with the same values as the input array but I am required for this assignment to use strdup to copy the elements. So far I have something like this:

```
typedef struct {
  char  *argv[ARG_MAX+1]; //ARG_MAX being a defined constant
  ...
} cmd_t;
```

```
cmd_t *cmd_new(char *argv[]){
  cmd_t *cmd;
  for (int i = 0; i < ARG_MAX; i++){ //Last element must be NULL
    cmd->argv[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
  }
  ...
}
```

Though I am getting a warning which worries me.

```
warning: ‘cmd’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     cmd->argv[i] = strdup(argv[i]);
```

I assume my approach is rather naive and if I could get some pointers in the right direction it would be splendid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
  /* declared here as a pointer, but is not yet pointing to a valid object */
  cmd_t *cmd; 
  for (int i = 0; i < ARGMAX; i++){

    /* cmd has not yet been initialised. It's pointing at garbage! */
    cmd->argv[i] = strdup(argv[i]); 
  }
```

You possibly want to initialise the cmd pointer to some valid memory first...

```cpp
  cmd_t *cmd = malloc(sizeof(cmd_t));
```

Comment: `cmd_t *cmd = malloc(sizeof *cmd);` is a nice alternative. Easier to code right, review and maintain.